# rails api: send curl in controller test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl

I'm building a Rails API, and I'm writing a test that sending a `curl` request works. This seems to be a testing issue, because an actual `curl` request works:

```
$ curl -X POST -d temperature=68 localhost:3000/temperature_readings.json
# => {"status":200}
```

Here's the controller method:

```
def create
  TemperatureReading.create(temperature: params[:temperature])
  render json: { status: 200 }
end
```

Here's the test:

```
context 'works via a curl request' do
  it 'works' do
    system "curl -X POST -d 'temperature=68' #{temperature_readings_url(format: 'json')}"
    expect(TemperatureReading.last.temperature).to eq(68)
  end
end
```

I'm getting an error from curl that `test.host` does not resolve:

`curl: (6) Could not resolve host: test.host`

That makes sense, because when I call `temperature_readings_url(format: 'json')` from within `pry` in that method, I get `http://test.host/temperatures.json`.

Is there a better way to test that my controller can successfully handle a `curl` request and create the correct record with the correct attributes?

#### What I've Tried

- I made sure that `protect_from_forgery with: :null_session` is set in `ApplicationController` so that it doesn't fail with an exception when it can't find the token
- I tried adding `-H 'Content-Type:application/json'` to the `curl` request to make sure it's hitting the `json` format in the controller. But it really seems to boil down to the fact that the working URL in the testing environment is `test.host`.
- So I explicitly set `request.host` to `localhost:3000` in the test, which felt a little hacky. But then of course it just posted to my dev database and not my test database, so the test still failed.

Answer (score 0):

Your app doesn't know its host outside the request context, so you have to provide it anyway. This is also hacky: 
`temperature_readings_url(format: 'json', host: 'localhost:3000')`.

But you can define it globally in `config/enviroments/test.rb`: 
`Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'localhost:3000'`
so in test enviroment all url helpers will return localhost:3000 as host by default.

Comment: But as I mentioned in my third bullet, if this is posting to localhost (backed by dev db), but checking the test db, the test will fail.